# Which motherboard does my early 2008 iMac have?

Tags: imac, system-information, motherboard

I'm helping someone with a memory upgrade for their 20-inch Core 2 Duo 2.66 GHz iMac (early 2008), which is all the information I can get about the computer from Apple's serial number checker.  When I try to select memory at memory4less.com, it shows two different models with these specs, with different motherboards: MB324LL/A and MB391LL/A.  How do I tell which this computer is, without cracking it open?

Comment: Do the details on EveryMac help? http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-2.66-20-inch-aluminum-early-2008-penryn-specs.html

Comment: I'd try the checker at http://crucial.com whether you end up buying from there or not, it takes the guesswork out of it

Comment: @espertus It shouldn't make any difference for you upgrading the memory.

Comment: @Rob memory4less.com shows different memory, depending on the motherboard.

Comment: Regarding Mac computers, they are called "Logic boards"